# Create a panel data frame

Tags: r, panel

I would like to create a panel from a dataset that has one observation for every given time period such that every unit has a new observation for every time period. Using the following example:

```
id <- seq(1:4)
year <- c(2005, 2008, 2008, 2007)
y <- c(1,0,0,1)
frame <- data.frame(id, year, y)
frame

 id year y
1  1 2005 1
2  2 2008 0
3  3 2008 0
4  4 2007 1
```

For each unique ID, I would like there to be a unique observation for the year 2005, 2006, 2007, and 2008 (the lower and upper time periods on this frame), and set the outcome y to 0 for all the times in which there isn't an existing observation, such that the new frame looks like:

```
 id year y
1  1 2005 1
2  1 2006 0
3  1 2007 0
4  1 2008 0
....
13  4 2005 0
14  4 2006 0
15  4 2007 1
16  4 2008 0
```

I haven't had much success with loops; Any and all thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) reshape2** Create a grid `g` of all years and `id` values crossed and `rbind` it with `frame`.

Then using the reshape2 package `cast` `frame` from long to wide form and then `melt` it back to long form. Finally rearrange the rows and columns as desired.

The lines ending in one # are only to ensure that every year is present so if we knew that were the case those lines could be omitted.  The line ending in ## is only to rearrange the rows and columns so if that did not matter that line could be omitted too.

```
library(reshape2)

g <- with(frame, expand.grid(year = seq(min(year), max(year)), id = unique(id), y = 0)) #
frame <- rbind(frame, g) #

wide <- dcast(frame, year ~ id, fill = 0, fun = sum, value.var = "y")
long <- melt(wide, id = "year", variable.name = "id", value.name = "y")

long <- long[order(long$id, long$year), c("id", "year", "y")] ##
```

giving:

```
> long
   id year y
1   1 2005 1
2   1 2006 0
3   1 2007 0
4   1 2008 0
5   2 2005 0
6   2 2006 0
7   2 2007 0
8   2 2008 0
9   3 2005 0
10  3 2006 0
11  3 2007 0
12  3 2008 0
13  4 2005 0
14  4 2006 0
15  4 2007 1
16  4 2008 0
```

**2) aggregate** A shorter solution would be to run just the two lines that end with # above and then follow those with an `aggregate` as shown.   This solution uses no addon packages.

```
g <- with(frame, expand.grid(year = seq(min(year), max(year)), id = unique(id), y = 0)) #
frame <- rbind(frame, g) # 

aggregate(y ~ year + id, frame, sum)[c("id", "year", "y")]
```

This gives the same answer as solution (1) except as noted by a commenter solution (1) above makes `id` a factor whereas it is not in this solution.

Comment: Any particular reason for reshaping here? Wouldn't this suffice? `merge(frame, g, by=c("id", "year"), all=TRUE)` (where `g` doesn't have `y=0`)

Comment: Not if you want to be able to omit the computation of `g` if it were known that all years were present.

Comment: I don't think I get it, sorry. Where do you eliminate computation of `g` in your case when it's known all years are present?

Comment: In the first solution just omit the lines that end in # as stated in the answser and you will see it still gives the same result provided all years are present in the input `frame`.

Comment: got it. Note that `id` will be a factor here.

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(frame, key=c("id", "year"))
comb <- CJ(1:4, 2005:2008) # like 'expand.grid', but faster + sets key
ans <- DT[comb][is.na(y), y:=0L] # perform a join (DT[comb]), then set NAs to 0
#     id year y
#  1:  1 2005 1
#  2:  1 2006 0
#  3:  1 2007 0
#  4:  1 2008 0
#  5:  2 2005 0
#  6:  2 2006 0
#  7:  2 2007 0
#  8:  2 2008 0
#  9:  3 2005 0
# 10:  3 2006 0
# 11:  3 2007 0
# 12:  3 2008 0
# 13:  4 2005 0
# 14:  4 2006 0
# 15:  4 2007 1
# 16:  4 2008 0
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not an elegant solution, but anyway:

```
df <- expand.grid(id=id, year=unique(year))
frame <- frame[frame$y != 0,]
df$y <- 0
df2 <- rbind(frame, df)
df2 <- df2[!duplicated(df2[,c("id", "year")]),]
df2 <- df2[order(df2$id, df2$year),]
rownames(df2) <- NULL
df2
# id year y
# 1   1 2005 1
# 2   1 2006 0
# 3   1 2007 0
# 4   1 2008 0
# 5   2 2005 0
# 6   2 2006 0
# 7   2 2007 0
# 8   2 2008 0
# 9   3 2005 0
# 10  3 2006 0
# 11  3 2007 0
# 12  3 2008 0
# 13  4 2005 0
# 14  4 2006 0
# 15  4 2007 1
# 16  4 2008 0
```