# Creating panel-data with a lot of data in R

Tags: r, panel-data

I currently have a problem combining a lot of data into panel-data. I have found this solution which helps me for "smaller" solutions: [Panel Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21007913/create-a-panel-data-frame) but I cannot apply this to a "bigger" format.

I will try to make a coding example:
From the package ‘datasets’:

```
df_1 = WorldPhones # In my case, years 2000-2014 and 43 columns (districts)
df_2 = WorldPhones # In my case, there is different data here
df_3 = WorldPhones # ""
df_4 = WorldPhones # ""
```

Each data frame contains different values for each of the 43 districts. I have given every district a unique id (1 to 43). The 43 districts are comparable to the 7 regions (continents) given in the data set WorldPhones. 
Every dataframe only contains one variable for each district and each year. Let's say df_1 contains the variable X1, df_2 contains X2 and so on.
I want to get this data into the "long" format, somethink like this:

```
Id  Year  X1     X2    X3   ...
1   1951  45939  21574 2876  
1   1956  60423  29990 4708 
1   1957  64721  32510 5230 
1   1958  68484  35218 6662 
1   1959  71799  37598 6856 
1   1960  76036  40341 8220
1   1961  79831  43173 9053 
2   1951  45939  21574 2876  
2   1956  60423  29990 4708 
2   1957  64721  32510 5230 
2   1958  68484  35218 6662 
2   1959  71799  37598 6856 
2   1960  76036  40341 8220
2   1961  79831  43173 9053 
...
43  1951  45939  21574 2876  
43  1956  60423  29990 4708 
43  1957  64721  32510 5230 
43  1958  68484  35218 6662 
43  1959  71799  37598 6856 
43  1960  76036  40341 8220
43  1961  79831  43173 9053
```

Unfortunately, I really don't know how to do this, except "brute force" which would be to write "it down" 43 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite easy using either `tidyr` or `reshape2`. IMHO, every R user should learn to use these 2 packages along with `data.table`,`dplyr`.

```
library("datasets")
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr) 
WorldPhones <- data.frame(WorldPhones)    # matrix format to data.frame
WorldPhones$Year <- rownames(WorldPhones) # create Year column
df_1 <- df_2 <- df_3 <- WorldPhones       # 
# transform to long format using melt from reshape2
df_1 <- melt(df_1, id.vars = "Year", variable.name = "Id", value.name="X")      
df_2 <- df_3 <- df_1                      # similarly for df_2, df_3. 
# merge the datasets using left_join from dplyr   
 df_1 %>%
  left_join(df_2,  by=c("Year", "Id")) %>%
  left_join(df_3,  by=c("Year", "Id")) %>% head
  Year     Id   X.x   X.y     X
1 1951 N.Amer 45939 45939 45939
2 1956 N.Amer 60423 60423 60423
3 1957 N.Amer 64721 64721 64721
4 1958 N.Amer 68484 68484 68484
5 1959 N.Amer 71799 71799 71799
6 1960 N.Amer 76036 76036 76036
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library("data.table")
dt_1 <- setDT(WorldPhones)
dt_1 <- melt(dt_1, id.vars = "Year", variable.name = "Id", value.name="X")
setkey(dt_1, Year, Id)
dt_2 <- dt_3 <- dt_1
dt_1[dt_2][dt_3]         
    Year       Id     X   i.X i.X.1
 1: 1951   N.Amer 45939 45939 45939
 2: 1951   Europe 21574 21574 21574
 3: 1951     Asia  2876  2876  2876
 4: 1951   S.Amer  1815  1815  1815
 5: 1951  Oceania  1646  1646  1646
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I used your first suggestion with dplyr and reshape2. :)

Comment: Do you also know a simple trick to copy the same data (only 1 column) into all regions (districts)? In this case, the data is equal in all regions.

Comment: Lets say I have a data frame with just 2 columns. One for the years, the other one for the interest rates. The interest rates are the same for all regions, therefore I can use the same data for every region (Id) in the paneldata analysis. (by creating duplicates of this data into every id?)

Comment: If I got you right, suppose you have `interest` rate in chronological order. Depending on how your merged panel data is ordered (by `Id` as in dplyr or by `Year` as in data.table answer), you can just concatenate, either `rep(interest, each=n)` or `rep(interest, n)` where `n` is the number of regions. Hope this helps.

Comment: I used `data.frame(rep(list(df_interest), 43))`. But this also replicates the years 43 times. Edit: Found a solution thanks to your comment! Thanks!